# How to write a hive script to return the data in the expected format

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
impression  lineid1 cookieid1
impression  lineid1 cookieid2
impression  lineid1 cookieid3
impression  lineid1 cookieid4
impression  lineid1 cookieid1
impression  lineid2 cookieid1
impression  lineid2 cookieid2
impression  lineid3 cookieid1
impression  lineid1 cookieid1
impression  lineid3 cookieid3
impression  lineid4 cookieid1
impression  lineid4 cookieid2
impression  lineid1 cookieid1
impression  lineid4 cookieid3
impression  lineid4 cookieid4
conversion      cookieid1
conversion      cookieid2
conversion      cookieid3
conversion      cookieid3
```

All events(ie,impression, conversion) have cookie_ids. For all events in "impression", I would like to know how many times those cookie_id(s) occur in conversion.

I want the o/p like this:

```
line_id1    cookie_id1  count=1
line_id1    cookie_id2  count=1
line_id1    cookie_id3  count=1
line_id2    cookie_id1  count=1
line_id2    cookie_id2  count=1
```

How to write a hive script to return the data in the expected format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table on itself by cookieid. Filter lines where the left row is an impression and the right row a conversion. Group by lineid and cookieid to get the counts.

```
select lineid, cookieid, count(*) as count
from table t1 join table t2
on t1.cookieid = t2.cookieid
where t1.event = 'impression'
and t2.event = 'conversion'
group by lineid, cookieid
```

This query will not return combinations for which there is no conversion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the below script: 

SELECT  e1.line_id, e1.cookie_id, count(e2.cookie_id))
FROM events e1
LEFT OUTER JOIN events e2
ON e1.cookie_id = e2.cookie_id 
WHERE e1.event = 'impression'  
AND e2.event = 'conversion' 
GROUP BY e1.line_id, e1.cookie_id;

I'm getting the below output: 

line_id1    cookie_id1  count=4
line_id1    cookie_id2  count=1
line_id1    cookie_id3  count=2
line_id2    cookie_id1  count=1
line_id2    cookie_id2  count=1
 
I want the o/p like this:
line_id1    cookie_id1  count=1
line_id1    cookie_id2  count=1
line_id1    cookie_id3  count=1